# Shared rep credits for edits

Tags: feature-request, reputation, editing

If you do an edit on a question, surely you should be eligible for a share of any rep points on that question?

Similar to the usual affiliate programs.

Comment: You haven't thought that through, have you?

Comment: working for me, so yeah i have

Comment: Imagine this was main, should Martin Sleziak (who added a tag on your question) share the downvotes with you? I don't think so... And what about all the people who would make trivial edits to high-ranked posts in the hope of getting rep?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi; well its not the main site for one, and to be fair, yes he should

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: There are no reputation points for meta, so which reputation points are we talking about?

Comment: @robjohn; the one's I am owed for my participation

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: There are no reputation points for editing someone else's post (except for suggested edits), so if reputation is why you are here, then don't spend time editing others' posts since you are not "owed" reputation for doing that.

Comment: Besides, reputation does not necessarily measure participation. Some days I put a lot of work into this site and get very little reputation. Some days I answer one question that happens to be very popular and get a lot.

Answer (score 23):

Nope. If you are to share in the upvotes of an edited question, then you're to share in the downvotes as well. And that would discourage the editing of questions that already have downvotes. This would hurt new users the most.

Put yourself in the shoes a new user. You don't know anything about how math formatting works on this site. You ask a question that is basic for most but you genuinely don't know the answer. Your question gets swiftly closed for being "off-topic" after no one helped you with the math formatting because they were too afraid of their scores getting dinged.

Also, you must have noticed that when you crossed the 2k threshold, you no longer get the two points when your edits to others' questions are approved. At this level, we're expected to edit questions altruistically, without concern for our own scores.